# Switch Case not working

Tags: jquery

```
        $("select[name=program]").change(function () {
            switch ($("select[name=program]").val()) {
                case 'Women\'s':
                    $("tr#levelCheck").html(
                        "<th>Level</th>" +
                        "<td>" + 
                            "<select name='level'>" +
                                "<option value='Senior'>Senior</option>" +
                                "<option value='Junior'>Junior</option>" +
                            "</select>" +
                        "</td>"
                    );
                default:
                $("tr#levelCheck").html("");
            }
        });
```

Here is my html

```
<tr>
    <th>Program</th>
    <td>{html_options name="program" output="$program" values="$program"}</td>
</tr>
<tr id="levelCheck"></tr>
```

I just want my other menu to show up when I select one of my other menu options from the program dropdown. Basically, I select Women's, another menu shows up below and I am off to the races. Why isn't my dropdown displaying when I select my Women's Option?

Comment: Have you added any rudimentary debugging statements (like an alert();) to display what the action value of you jQuery selector is when you select "Women's"?

Comment: @Nik's answer is right, but if you want to know what is happening, please read: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/07/javascript-switch-statement-quirks/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a break before your default case. Right now, you build the menu and then you fall into the default case and your HTML is cleared.

```
$("select[name=program]").change(function () {
            switch ($("select[name=program]").val()) {
                case 'Women\'s':
                    $("tr#levelCheck").html(
                        "<th>Level</th>" +
                        "<td>" + 
                            "<select name='level'>" +
                                "<option value='Senior'>Senior</option>" +
                                "<option value='Junior'>Junior</option>" +
                            "</select>" +
                        "</td>"
                    );
                    break;
                default:
                    $("tr#levelCheck").html("");
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: give him some code ;-) `case: $("tr#levelCheck").html(...); break; default: $("tr#levelCheck").html("");`

Comment: Plausible? This is *the* solution.